# Android 4.2 lock screen only widget not possible. Bug?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, lockscreen, android-appwidget

When I define an appwidget as lock screen only (android:widgetCategory="keyguard" in the widget info xml file) it can still be selected as a home screen widget.

Runtime checks show that widgetcategory=2 (=lock screen only), but when on the home screen it has category 1 (=home screen).

Just want to know if this is intended behavior or an Android 4.2 bug.
Problem exists in 4.2 and 4.2.1. Verified on simulator, Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 7.

Answer (score 1):

This feels like a bug, and [a bug report has already been filed on it](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40371).